# Semantically vague sentence (I think?)

Tags: grammaticality, ambiguity, semantics

> I spotted it in a junk shop in Bridport, a roll-top desk. The man said it **was** early nineteenth century, and oak.

I think the author can use "be+of" here, but why only "be"???

Comment: _Early nineteenth century_ acts like an adjective describing the desk - as in _the man said it was old_.

Comment: As with **oak**. Both can be used as nouns or adjectives.

Comment: @KateBunting i want to know more about it, plz help me anyway.

Comment: No, you can't insert "of" here. It doesn't work.  The sentence is correct as written.

Comment: You could use "from the early nineteenth century", but you need "the", and "from" is better than "of" (which would sound odd).

Comment: @StuartF I think —we need to interpret  the sentence as per our own common sense.I could not find anywhere a time expression is being used as an adjectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shop man used two expressions to describe the desk. In the same way that he might have used adjectives - "The desk is large and old" - he said that it was *[made in the] early nineteenth century* and *[made of] oak wood*. The phrase giving the approximate date, and the name of the type of wood, act as though they were adjectives.

Comment: Are there any grammar rules about this?

Comment: Well, here's an explanation of [adjective phrases](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective-phrase/).