# Be verb+Noun(Used as an adjective)

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns, syntax

I spotted it in a junk shop in Bridport, a roll-top desk. The man said it was early **nineteenth century**, and **oak**.

I have a doubt regarding any grammar rules as to this "be+Noun"(using as adjectives).

**It was early nineteenth century** my question is in which sense **be** is being used here. I want to know grammar rules where this types of structure i can found with proper explanation..

Comment: Hi. Not sure what the confusion is here. There is nothing wrong with the grammar.  Why do you think it might be wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Semantically vague sentence (I think?)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/336825/semantically-vague-sentence-i-think)

Comment: "Nineteenth century" and "oak" are not adjectives. They are noun phrases functioning as predicative complements of "be".

Comment: @BillJ I have just edited the question

Comment: "be" is used in the normal way, as a copula. Why do you think it might be something else? Please clarify what you mean by "*in which sense*".

Comment: @gotube **be** as a main verb used in many senses so when we use **be** in this way what it actually means, and i want explanation from grammar point of view.

Comment: Didn't you ask almost exactly this same question about a week ago?  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/336825/semantically-vague-sentence-i-think

Comment: @stangdon no, This time I want some grammar knowledge as to this types of structure. How this type of structure is used in grammar?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what is confusing you, but it's easy to use nouns like adjectives in English.  "It is oak" (where *oak* means "made of oak") is exactly the same grammar as "He is tall."

Comment: @user477291 You'll have to give some examples of what you mean by "in which sense" or "means". The verb "be" rarely has any *meaning* -- it only has *functions*. In this sentence, the function is *copula*. It's also a "linking verb", if that helps.

Comment: @stangdon **It is oak** is same as **it is made of oak— i want this topic of grammar to learn. Where can I find.

Comment: @BillJ Could you elaborate a little? I'm writing an answer and worried I'm parsing the sentence incorrectly because of your comment. It looks to me like 'it' is the subject and 'is' is the verb, with 'nineteenth century oak (desk)' the direct object - what it's being. That is, the man is saying the desk has the characteristics of being nineteenth century and oak.

Comment: I finally understood the question. We do not say in English: This is of the 19th century. We say: This [whatever] is 19th century. But in the past: The man said it was 19th century. That is reported speech.

Comment: @Lambie can you elaborate your answer plz, your answer seems  correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dating an object or person:

The man says **the desk is** 19th century.

The man said the **desk was** 19th century.

***was*** is used as reported speech. *However, since the desk's date will not change it could also be: The man said the desk is 19th c.* Your choice of whether to say *was* or *is*.

When something is from a time period, we don't use *of.* We say the date or time period: **This is 2nd century pottery**.

This is 20th century art. This is 20th century.

Those **mean** from the 20th century.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible I'm misunderstanding your question, but it looks like 'be' is being used by the man simply to describe the characteristics of the desk.

The indirection between us and the speaker might be creating confusion - what the man said about the roll top desk was probably the following:

"It's nineteenth century oak."

Or, if he was a little verbose "It is a nineteenth century oak desk", or, finally, "It is a desk made in the nineteenth century out of oak."

Generally, the structure "A (is/was/were/will be) B", without an article like 'a' or 'an', means one of the following:

- Item A has the characteristic B ('the desk is steel', 'their arrows were aflame') - in this usage, B must be an adjective. Note that 'steel' is used here in the meaning 'made out of steel', which is typical for nouns that are materials used to make other things.
- Item A and item B are the same item ('I am Iron Man') - in this usage, A and B are *used* as nouns in the sentence, whatever parts of speech they normally are, because they're being discussed as words or concepts.

Comment: I was confused about**it was early nineteenth century** How A and B is same **The roll-top desk** how can be nineteenth century.

Comment: That would be the usage in the first bullet point: the desk (item A) is nineteenth century (item B, an adjective describing when it was made)