# With vs without Preposition rule?

Tags: prepositions, syntax

**The documents is sixteenth century.=The documents is from the sixteenth century.**

Why are both the sentences are same?? What is the syntax rule applied here?

Comment: The prepositionless version is using ***sixteenth century*** adjectivally, as in *This is a **sixteenth century** document*, or *This is an **old** document* *(The document is **old**).* It just so happens *[the] **sixteenth century*** can be used with a preposition as a ***noun***, even though you can't do that with ***old***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers School bus =we can't say the bus is school.government policies =The policies is government. (Why so?)

Comment: Bear in mind not everyone would accept prepositionless *The document is sixteenth century* in the first place (but obviously *The document is old* is fine). I'm not exactly sure why they're different, but the fact that the *sixteenth century* version is only "marginally valid" (to me, but not to everyone) might be significant. It may simply be that ***sixteenth century, school, government*** are all ***nouns*** (that can be used adjectivally as ***noun adjuncts***), whereas ***old*** isn't a noun - it's an adjective, pure and simple.

Comment: Look, I have already explained this to you at great length. So what exactly are you doing? I told you that when we say "X is y century", it means FROM that century. There is more than one way to say things. And I resent your taking my explanation and reposting it as a question.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/337107/be-verbnounused-as-an-adjective

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please do not stir the pot. Of course, **people say all the time** things like This X is Y century. Just go to any antique shop and ask the owners. And there is no rule here at all. There are simply two ways to say something. You keep answering in comments and it is quite unfair to others.

Comment: **Pandolfini’s expert T.Zecchini wasn’t able to discern if the vase is 18th century or 19th**. https://www.artmarketmonitor.com/2014/11/05/italian-site-claims-internet-record-sale-e7-445m/ In fact, that's how art experts say a thing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sixteenth Century" is a noun when it is used as the name for a period of time. But like many nouns, it can be used as an adjective - for example, a '*history teacher*' is a teacher of history and a '*bath towel*' is a towel for use when taking a bath. Likewise, a '*sixteenth-century document*' would be a document from the sixteenth century.

Lots of nouns for periods of time are used as adjectives: *Roman artefacts, Victorian housing, Jurassic dinosaurs etc*.

And just like any other adjective, you can use them at the end of a sentence. So, just as you could say "*this is a Victorian house*" **or** "*this house is Victorian*", you can also say "*this is a sixteenth-century document*" **or** "*this document is sixteenth-century*".

Comment: Those are my sentences in the question, which I used to explain X is Y century.

Comment: Take a look: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/337107/be-verbnounused-as-an-adjective